# How to hide COM object Dispatched from Python

Tags: python, com

I'm using COM in Python and I want the object to run in background - hidden.
With Excel I do:

```
Import win32com.client 
Excel=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
Excel.Visible=1
```

but my application do not have property `.Visible` - is there any other way to hide it? Maybe some special parameter to Dispatch?

Thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know your application title or class, you can hide it via ShowWindow:

```
import win32com.client 
import win32con
import win32gui
import time

print "Start"
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
excel.Visible = 1   # Visible via automation
time.sleep(2)
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Microsoft Excel")  # Class or title
print "Hide"
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_HIDE) # Hide via Win32Api
time.sleep(2)
print "Show"
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOW) # Show via Win32Api
time.sleep(2)

###
```

HTH,
Pablo