# Python - win32com visible false not working?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to convert an excel file to PDF. Using [Print chosen worksheets in excel files to pdf in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683376/print-chosen-worksheets-in-excel-files-to-pdf-in-python) and [Python - Converting XLSX to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326782/python-converting-xlsx-to-pdf), I wrote the code below.

This converts the excel to PDF without a problem but it opens the excel file. I thought the point of the `.Visible = False` was to prevent this? I would like the excel object to stay hidden because I am doing this to over 100 files and I do not want excel opening up 100 times.

```
import win32com.client
import os
import re

nm = 'Sample.xlsx'

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('{0}\\{1}'.format(os.getcwd(), nm))
wb.WorkSheets('Report').Select()
nm_pdf = re.sub('.xlsx', '.pdf', nm, count = 1)
wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, '{0}\\{1}'.format(os.getcwd(), nm_pdf))
#excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Is this the answer you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439689/how-to-hide-com-object-dispatched-from-python

Comment: @Sirsmorgasboard, that is a workaround for an application that does not have the `.Visible` property. But OP says that Excel does have that property, and since I am using Excel, `.Visible` should work right?

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the methods above worked for me but finally this did the job, maybe it's gonna be of some use for someone:

```
excel.ScreenUpdating = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
excel.EnableEvents = False
```

*set it all back to `True` after you finish processing the file.

Comment: This works for me if there is already an Excel Application open, not sure if that's the same case for everyone else

Answer (score 3):

to anyone who has this problem, this is what helped me:

```
excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Interactive = False
excel.Visible = False
```

The "Interactive = False" part is what i was missing. Visible set to False by itself didn't do the trick. Also don't forge to close the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when starting the program with an Excel sheet open, it would continue to open and run as though set to Visible = True. If I started the program with no Excel file open, it would run as expected (not opening Excel).

```
excel = w32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Interactive = False
excel.Visible = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
```