# Visible property of Power point application in win32com under python is not working when set to false

Tags: python, powerpoint, win32com, python-pptx

The visible property of Powerpoint application in the win32com package under python is not working when set to 'False'. It was working when the visible property was set to true and the pptx gets opened once the given piece of code executes. I don't want the PPT to be opened. Could you please suggest some corrections in the given code.  I was getting the below error when I executed the below piece of code.

```
ExcelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = False
workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.open(r'C:\Users\aju.mathew.thomas\Desktop\PBC\Pepsi\PBC\Performance Reports\2019\PPT\PerformanceReportMetrics.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Summary")
excelrange = worksheet.Range("A1:R20")


PptApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
PptApp.Visible = False
z = excelrange.Copy()

PPtPresentation = PptApp.Presentations.Open(r'C:\Users\aju.mathew.thomas\Desktop\PBC\Pepsi\PBC\Performance Reports\2019\PPT\Performance Reports.pptx')
pptSlide = PPtPresentation.Slides.Add(1,11)
title = pptSlide.Shapes.Title
title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = 'Metrics Summary'
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(z)
PPtPresentation.SaveAs(r'C:\Users\aju.mathew.thomas\Desktop\PBC\Pepsi\PBC\Performance Reports\2019\PPT\Performance2.pptx',1)
workbook.Save()
workbook.Close(True)
```

**Error messages**

> PptApp.Visible = False,     self.*oleobj*.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0,
>   invoke_type, 0, value) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception
>   occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft PowerPoint', 'Application.Visible : Invalid
>   request.  Hiding the application window is not allowed.', '', 0,
>   -2147188160), None)

Comment: have a look at this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439689/how-to-hide-com-object-dispatched-from-python), the answer is with Excel, but the question mention a COM object not allowing Visible to False, like in your case with ppt, it may work

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
WithWindow=False
```

in open statement.
like this:

```
PPtPresentation = PptApp.Presentations.Open(r'C:\demo.pptx', WithWindow=False)
```